# Cannot log into my SQL Docker instance with SSMS

Tags: sql-server, docker, powershell, ssms

I have been having lots of issues trying to set up an connect to a local SQL instance.

In PS I ran

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<myPassword14>" -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 -h sql1 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

Then I attempted to login into SSMS using the credentials "sa" (is "sa" the default username?) and "myPassword14." (password has been replaced with fake password here).

Then I get the following error.
[image]

Comment: Have you opened port 1433 on the firewall?

Comment: I have just opened the port for 1433 and I am still getting the error "login failed for user 'sa' "

Answer (score 1):

The password guidelines are quite strict. Try a password with upper and lowercase characters, numbers and special characters.
Also the password must NOT be found in a dictionary (I assume they are talking about password dictionaries, not the ones you would look up the spelling of words in).

`sa` is definetly the right username. I vaguely remember `SA_PASSWORD` being changed to `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` at some point, so as a last resort you might also try that.

Also I set the `MSSQL_PID` environment variable to "Developer", not sure if that makes a difference. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash you will also find the exact password guidelines there.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. It is still not working with the error "Login failed for user 'sa' " I tried the MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD as well and making the password more complicated and ensuring it fits with all requirements. No error in PS.